# Table width applied only to the first column

Tags: html, html-table, width

I want to know why the first column **only** gets 100% in width. Now, I know there was a question just like this asked. But I know how to correct it, I'm just interested in WHY it's actually this way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think it is how the browser renders the page. All ``<td>`` tags have a 100% in width. It first puts the first ``<td>`` tag width 100% and when it add the next one, it just take enough wor it to fit

Comment: Ok thank you, but why aren't the rest of the <td>'s and <th>'s affected though?

Comment: they are. It happens every time the ``<tr>`` tags load